# How to get around airbnb eslint import/prefer-default-export rule when using index.js for exports

Tags: javascript, import, export, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

For cases like this,
`/ACollectionOfTinyComponent/index.js`

```
import Container from './Container';
export {
  Container,
};
```

So the index.js becomes a directory to include other small parts without having to write each Component Name out all the time.
So in this case, we can import a component in another component like following:

```
import {Container} from './ACollectionOfTinyComponent'

//then use Container in the code here
```

Is this a bad practice? Since if I have airbnb linter enable then I got error linting of

`Prefer default export  import/prefer-default-export`

it asks me to add `default` but that will cause compile error

Answer (score 2):

I found out that because I added only **ONE** import & export for the `index.js`. But if I add more than one its fine!
For example, if I do

```
import Container from './Container';
import Ezeewei from './Ezeewei';
export {
  Container,
  Ezeewei,
};
```

Note that I added one more import of `Ezeewei`.

Then the linting rule will pass!

Answer (score 0):

> it asks me to add default but that will cause compile error

You must be using the wrong syntax for exporting a default.

```
export { name1 as default, … };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax

> `import {Container}` ... Is this a bad practice?

Yes. If you have a single entry point into a component (like a a class), you should export it as the default rather than a named export. The designers of the language gave default imports and exports a special syntax to promote it as the primary use case.

http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#default-exports-are-favored